# Java - Comparator

Tags: java, android, arraylist, comparator

I got question on Comparator - I need to sort my `ArrayList<Integer> numbersToSort`, which keeps numbers- links to `competition.participant.get(numbers.get(index))` - so I have a main Object - competition which has a List of participants object. So, my `ArrayList<Integer> numbersToSor`t keeps which numbers of `competition.participants` should I use. The only way I figured how to sort my `ArrayList<Integer> numbersToSort` (which I later will feed to my ListView Adapter) is to make another "parallel"`List<Participants>` where I shall copy participants from main object, competition and store in them their number in `ArrayList<Integer> numbersToSort` so I can later assemble a new `ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers` from sorted `List<Participant> participants`. Are you still there ?:)

```
    public class ParticipantIndexComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
        final List<Participant> participants;       
        public ParticipantIndexComparator(ArrayList<Integer> numbersToSort) {
            participants=new ArrayList<Participant>();
            for (int i=0;i<numbersToSort.size();i++)
            { participants.add(i,competition.participant.get(numbersToSort.get(i))); participants.get(i).comparator=numbersToSort.get(i);}

        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            long l1 = participants.get(i1).kpTime.get(kpSelected); 
//time from selected checkpoint
            long l2 = participants.get(i2).kpTime.get(kpSelected);
            return (long) compare(l1, l2);
        }
    }
```

well, the problem is the last `return (long) compare(l1, l2);` - yes, I know it's not right but it's the 30th attempt :) please correct what's wrong

Comment: Why cast to long?  Have you tried removing the cast?  That looks like a recursive call.  Try returning (int)(l1-l2)

Comment: Correction. Need to compare the int values passed to the compare() method.  return i1 - i2.

Comment: because I need to compare exactly theese 2 longs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
    long l1 = participants.get(i1).kpTime.get(kpSelected); 
    long l2 = participants.get(i2).kpTime.get(kpSelected);
    return Long.compare(l1, l2);
}
```

Comment: The method compare(long, long) is undefined for the type Long

Comment: well, I've found that this is for Java 7+ and I'm on Android sdk which is 6, so it's a little different .  it's return Long.valueOf(l1).compareTo(Long.valueOf(l2)); - plz fix it and I'll accept answer.. well, your answer is right anyway:) so I'm accepting

Comment: @user2976267 Just copy method to your project: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Long.java?av=f And, You can use Java7 on Android: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio032released

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        public int compare(Integer lhs,
                        Integer rhs) {
                    return lhs - rhs;
                }
            });
```